# Android : native memory issue in webview

Tags: android, memory, android-webview

I am trying to show webpage in android webview. Webpage has a lot of processing. it will crash sometime. I saw a log files. but not OutOfMemory.

But I suspected memory problems. 
I know use native memory if use webview.
so I used this logs below.

```
Log.d("H","DalvikMaxHeapSize : "+(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024* 1024))+ "MB");

Log.d("H","AllocatedHeapSize : "+(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()/(1024* 1024))+ "MB");
```

results :

```
D/HeapSize(25466): Dalvik Max heap size   : 70MB


D/HeapSize(25466): Heap Allocated size    : 416MB
```

if the allocated native heap size is greater than a dalvik heap size, 
Running processes has died by ActivityManager.

Comment: so it looks like the JavaScript in the page is allocating too much memory forcing the system to kill your app. What's your question?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, system has a limit for dalvik heap, but no limit for native heap.

So, C/C++ can alloc much more memory then dalvik heap.

And the reason for your crash maybe is the bug in WebView(OR webkit).